# Handlng multiple clients with python websocket and nginx

Tags: python, python-3.x, nginx, networking, websocket

I have an app that communicates with a python websocket server through nginx. When each client makes a request, the python script does some stuff and informs the results and/or progress through the websocket connection. What I am currently doing is that I'm serving the websocket server at `localhost:5000`, telling nginx to listen for requests on port 8020 and route the client to `localhost:5000`

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
}

http {
    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default upgrade;
        '' close;
    }

    upstream websocket {
        #redirect clients to python script
        server localhost:5000;
    }

    server {
        listen 8020;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://websocket;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }
    }

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    gzip on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

The problem starts when multiple clients try to connect. The server has to run the script for each of the connected clients. When one is connected, no one else will connect.

This is how the python server handles the incoming requests

```
start_server = websockets.serve(receive_messages, "localhost", 5000)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)

try:
    print("running")
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("server crashed")
```

For each client `receive_messages()` has to finish to get the result and it's a lengthy function. This comprises one session for each client. But, I would like the server to accept multiple clients at a time to avoid delay. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turns out that you can simply solve the problem by removing `nginx` out of the picture. Just turn it off and then in the python code:

```
# just get rid of the host name
start_server = websockets.serve(receive_messages, 443)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)

try:
    print("running")
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("server crashed")
```

From now on, you'll be able to connect from any client device(s) at the same time by using your server's public ipv4 address. This seems to be a useless question for the most part. But, I sure hope it helps someone.